# Is it possible to add logic to a Coded UI (CUIT) automated tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, coded-ui-tests

Suppose I have a question on my application which reads, "Is there another member of your household?".

The question defaults to "No" on a radio button. If user selects "Yes", then a new component appears below the question. Is there a way to add conditional logic to Coded UI tests?

I don't require a detailed answer (although it would be appreciated), but I would like to know if it's possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

you can access the radio buttons value of Checked (true or false) thusly

```
if(radioButtonAreMoreHouseholdYES.Checked)
     //fill out more components here
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Like yonitdm noted, you can implement logic; however, it's not considered best practice (depending on your usage).

I would recommend writing two test - one where the user clicks 'YES', and then follow through with your test; and another where the user clicks 'NO', and then follow through with your test.

---

**Don’t write logic to test logic**

– Tests will be more complex than the
application

• There are multiple conditions per function

– Tests will require advanced skills to develop

• Non‐technical users will be excluded

– Tests will require extensive testing and
debugging

• Each logic branch will have to be exercised

– Test outcomes will become ambiguous

• Which failed, the application or the test?

Tests should be linear: (A > B > C > D > E)
Rather than: (A > if x then > B else C > D > E etc)

**When Is Logic Necessary?**

*Use logic to resolve obstacles to validation*

– Wait for or request system response

– Remove pop‐up window

*Don’t use logic to determine outcome*

– e.g. If expedited, change carrier

– e.g. If no inventory, add items

*Use linear pathways*

**– Different steps are different tests**

– Don’t trade usability for reusability

Comment: Thanks LuFaMa. Your answers seems to be on the spot.